# In Python is faster using "yield from" than yield in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, yield, yield-from

I tried multiple ranges for this example I let above:

```
import time


def reader():
    for a in range(100000000):
        yield a


def reader_wrapper(gen):
    for i in gen:
        yield i


def reader_wrapper_enhanced(gen):
    yield from gen


wrap = reader_wrapper_enhanced(reader())

start = time.perf_counter()

for i in wrap:
    ...

print("LAST: %s " % (time.perf_counter() - start))


wrap = reader_wrapper(reader())

start = time.perf_counter()

for i in wrap:
    ...

print("LAST: %s " % (time.perf_counter() - start))
```

My main question is that **yield from** is actually faster than a normal **yield** using loop.

Result for ranges:

Note: First result is the yield from and the second the yield.

| RANGE | Yield from | yield+loop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1.4644000000001156e-05 | 1.3087000000000168e-05 |
| 100000 | 0.010678924 | 0.012484127000000005 |
| 100000000 | 7.763497913 | 8.586706118000002 |
| 10000000000 | 794.1722820499999 | 807.1722820400000 |

In case it is faster, should not we always just use it in this kind of cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's faster when the inputs are long enough (though not by much, as you've seen), and yes, you may as well let Python do the work of yielding from the delegate iterator by default.

The one time you wouldn't want to do this is when you are delegating to a generator that you *don't* want to receive values from the caller sent with `.send` or `.throw`; when using plain `yield`, *your* generator receives them, when using `yield from`, the delegate generator receives them (usually the latter is what you want, and it's the primary reason `yield from` exists in the first place).

Comment: Thanks, I was using yield many times for projects but once I start using the yield from the performance was noticeable but I was not sure if it was "actually fast".